# The variable of the "typedef function" is initialized to NULL, and the compilation fails?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, null, typedef

The following code, VS2015 on my computer fails to compile,
**but it can be compiled successfully on other computers！**

```
#include <functional>
using namespace std::tr1;

typedef function<void()> OnRun;

class CTest
{
public:
    CTest()
    {
        //The compilation fails
        //if I comment out the compilation is successful
        pOnRun = NULL; // fail
        //pOnRun = NULL; // OK
    }

    ~CTest() {}

private:
    OnRun pOnRun;
};
```

The compilation error is as follows:

```
c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\type_traits(1494): error C2893: Failed to make function template "unknown-type std::invoke(_Callable &&,_Types &&...)" Specialization
```

Comment: A default-constructed `function` should already be "null".

Comment: By the way, the error message mentions [`std::invoke`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/invoke) which is a C++17 feature. Does VS2015 really support C++17?

Comment: Either way, VS2015 support C++11 out of the box, so you should have plain [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function), the `std::tr1` namespace is obsolete. And since the C++11 standard you should always use `nullptr` for null pointers, not the old C-compatibility macro `NULL`.

Comment: on VS it might be.  Using might cause  UB, imo. But here is also a problem of using macro  `pOnRun = NULL;`. `NULL` is often `#define NULL (0)` - how old VSs were defining it or `#define NULL ((void*) 0)` Use `nullptr` instead, NULL hails from C and by standard is defined only in certain header. `pOnRun = 0;` might be not a type-correct  use.

Comment: Why can VS2015 be compiled on other colleagues' computers? Is there any difference?

Answer (score 4):

The `typedef` is a red herring. `std::function` has multiple assignment operators, and none of them takes an `int`. Nor can it work via a converting constructor followed by copy assignment, as there is no converting constructor from  `int` either.  There's an assignment operator that takes `nullptr`, though.

`NULL` is an old-style C macro, and like all macro's suffers from type problems like this.

Comment: In this case it's `operator=`, but yeah, I saw my coworkers blundering on those garden rakes before.

Comment: Why can VS2015 be compiled on other colleagues' computers? Is there any difference?

Comment: @wsy: Might be a matter of the exact Visual Studio update they have installed. The chief goal for compilers is to correctly compile correct code. The exact error message for errors is much less important.

Answer (score 1):

From certain versions of VS's stddef.h

```
/* Define NULL pointer value */
#ifndef NULL
#ifdef __cplusplus
#define NULL    0
#else
#define NULL    ((void *)0)
#endif
#endif
```

*(I have many questions. To Microsoft developers why they had idea that C++ can do with just an `int`. And why there is C branch while their compiler doesn't support C environment at that point. There is some other headers which define NULL and in that case bug might not appear, depending on inclusion order.)*

Essentially, this doesn't work because `int(0)` cannot be implicitly casted to pointer of type `void(*)()` in this situation during overload resolution:

```
pOnRun = 0;
```

It's not recommended to use NULL in  C++ code, NULL is some expression that can be converted to a null pointer but it isn't guaranteed to be a null pointer. C++11 had defined `nullptr` variable of `nullptr_t` type convertible to a null pointer of any type to be used  portably.

Comment: Why can VS2015 be compiled on other colleagues' computers? Is there any difference?

Comment: @wsy not enough data to say that, but you can investigate by right-clicking on NULL and searching its definition. If it's absolutely same project, it can be that on your machine it picks up older SDK... or their SDK newer (e.g. because different OS versions or you didn't upgrade or your Studio picked up SDK installed with old Studio). If you just tried snipped on someone's else PC, then it's some headers may define it  differently.